# How to upload a file as user input in Github Actions workflow?

Tags: github, builds, github-actions, npm

I would like to upload .env file to a build in Github Actions. Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to store secrets in either secrets or specific environments in the repo:

```
Secrets:
https://github.com/**account_name**/**repo_name**/settings/secrets/actions
```

```
Environments:
https://github.com/**account_name**/**repo_name**/settings/environments
```

You can then access the secrets directly or generate an .env file when the GitHub actions runs.

In the workflow file access secrets with `${{ secrets.TOKEN }}` or generate an .env file and save secrets in there:

```
- name: do some stuff
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo TOKEN='${{ secrets.TOKEN }}' >> .env
          ...etc
```

If using environments to store secrets, don't forget to declare which environment is being used by that job! ([documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env))